# How to capture key down events at application level in Xamarin.Mac

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I have a Xamarin.Forms application and successfully capture application level key down events in WPF using the PreviewKeyDown event in the main window.

How do I do the same thing for Xamarin.Mac in AppDelegate or otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an `NSEvent` handler in the AppDelegate's `DidFinishLaunching` at the local level to monitor any combination of the `NSEventMask`.

```
public override void DidFinishLaunching(NSNotification notification)
{
    NSEvent.AddLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(NSEventMask.KeyDown, (NSEvent theEvent) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(theEvent);
        return theEvent;
    }); 

    Forms.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App());
    base.DidFinishLaunching(notification);
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MonitoringEvents/MonitoringEvents.html